# Load Balancing - Issues with ASP.NET SessionID

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, iis, haproxy

Our developers have recently said they added code for load balancing to work in our webapp. So I've spent the last 2 days and I'm at a loss on why its not working. First I found that the Site ID's where different on both IIS Servers so that is fixed. Anyways when balancing is setup the ASP.NET_SessionId keeps resetting as if its not getting stored properly in the Database. I have looked at the table and there is an entry in there.

Using HAproxy and have 2 Windows Servers 2016 IIS10. Looking at both servers the code below is what the devs said they added.

```
<sessionState timeout="15" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data source=DB1.resource.local;initial catalog=prodAPP;" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" />
<machineKey decryptionKey="REMOVEDFORSECURITY" validationKey="REMOVEDFORSECURITY" />
```

The backend for HAProxy

```
backend prodAPP
balance roundrobin
mode http
option httpchk GET https://prodAPP.com
http-check disable-on-404
option http-server-close
option forwardfor
option redispatch
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
server webprod01 10.10.10.10:443 check ssl verify none fall 3 rise 5 inter 60000 weight 10
server webprod02 10.10.10.11:443 check ssl verify none fall 3 rise 5 inter 60000 weight 10
```

Any ideas on what I can try to get this thing working?

---

**EDIT/UPDATE**

So I thought about taking the proxy/load balancer out of the mix and tested by just pointing my host file at webserver1 logging into the webapp and moving around. Then changing the host file to point to webserver2 and saved the host file. Then clicked a linked and continued to use the webapp without the ASP.NET_SessionId resetting.

So, what is going on with the proxy that is making the ASP.NET_SessionId reset?

---

**EDIT/UPDATE #2**
After figuring out my host file wasnt actually changing with properly the chrome session socket seem to stick to that original host. Only way to properly get it to change servers was to disconnect the virtual nic on the server.

Anyways its an issue with the web servers that I can tell now, but I'm still confused on why they are each thinking the session is different and generating a new key.

Comment: "as if its not getting stored properly in the Database" then have you checked the database?

Comment: Looking at the HAProxy configuration, it seems like the headers/cookies are getting dropped in subsequent request. I don't see "cookie" on the last two lines here that start with server webpro01.... Read here for more info https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/section_jyh_zhz_4r.html 

You may also want to read up on the prefix section of the documentation above. Good luck.

Comment: @LexLi - Yes, there is a value for AppId and AppName

Comment: @na-98 - Yeah, I've tried adding a ServerID cookie, that way when someone lands on the site they are sorta stuck to that webserver. However when I drain connections to that server they are on the session gets dropped and a new ASP.NET_SessionId is generated. But it seems like the session doesnt know about the shared session database connection. Any other ideas?